# Cluster analysis, 2-dimensional data?

Tags: python

I've got this cluster analysis module for performing a k-means test. I'm suppose to change part of one of the functions built in this module called readFile so instead of using 1 dimensional data, it can use 2 dimensional data. What does that mean?

```
def readFile( filename ):
    '''
    Reads data from a file and returns a dictionary indexed by
    line number (from 1).  Expects data to be one integer per line.
    '''
    datafile = open( filename, 'r' )
    datadict = {}

    key = 0
    for aline in datafile:
        key = key + 1
        score = int( aline )

        datadict[key] = [score]

    datafile.close()
    return datadict
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, since you mentioned you need a two dimation data structure, that you use lists of lists, so you can have how many dinamtions you need.

```
def readFile( filename ):
    datafile = open( filename, 'r')
    datalist = []

    key = 0
    for aline in datafile:
        key = key + 1
        score = int(aline)
        templist = [key, score]
        datalist.append(templist )

    datafile.close()
    return datalist
```

When you want to review the data, use:

```
key = datalist[pos][0]
int_data = datalist[pos][1]
```

Hope it helps